# compare the contents of two lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have two lists in my python code for my assignment:

```
exam_solutions = ['B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
student_answers = []
```

In my code, I have the user input the answer to the multiple choice question. Then I have it set to append the answer they entered into student_answers list. I want to compare the two lists and have it output the correct answers so I can display the percentage correct at a later time.

ex: `exam_solutions = ['B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
    student_answers = ['A','B','B','C','B','B','A','B','B','D']`

then after comparing the two lists am I able to output that 6 answers are correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Comment: I have already finished code for the assignment. I thought about posting it, but I felt just sharing my lists was enough to explain the issue I was having which was comparing lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the number of correct answers using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
correct = sum(x == y for x, y in zip(exam_solutions, student_answers))
```

`x == y` will be either `True` or `False` (which are `1` and `0` respectively).  We then find the sum of those, the number of correct answers.

---

To be a little more efficient, define your own customized function:

```
def correct_over_six(exam_solutions, student_answers):
    correct = 0
    for x, y in zip(exam_solutions, student_answers):
        correct += (x == y)
        if correct >= 6:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: This might sound dumb to ask, but would this change if my exam_solutions list is not all B as the answer?

Comment: @python_noob: This will find the total number of correct answers, not the number of answers minus the number of wrong answers.  If an answer is not given, it does not count as correct.

Comment: Okay awesome, then this is exactly what I was looking for. I was just using placeholder answers for now until I actually have the correct answers in my exam_solutions list.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help! Accepted my answer and since I'm so new to the site my upvote won't be displayed for everyone to see :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to put together each answer and solution respectively and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to count how many matches/correct answers are there:

```
>>> exam_solutions = ['B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
>>> student_answers = ['A','B','B','C','B','B','A','B','B','D']
>>> sum(a == b for a, b in zip(student_answers, exam_solutions))
6
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think to use zip () and sum (). After a couple hours of researching how to do this, I felt like I was in over my head with possible solutions.